# Is it possible to duplicate the Low reorder sets across the sites automatically?

Tags: low-reorder, duplicate

How can I duplicate the same Low Reorder sets that I have on my master site on all the duplicated sites on MSM?

I have 50 sites to deal with and I don't want to do it manually.

Thanks,
Salvo

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any hooks in place for when a MSM site is duplicated, so Low Reorder (nor any other 3rd party add-on) can do certain stuff when this happens.

If you don't want to do this via the CP, you'd have to manually create some SQL queries and insert those in the database yourself.